# Finding where a process reads in a file

Tags: linux, shell, strace

Is there a way to attach to a process and find out, not only which files it is reading from, but what the read locations (byte offsets) of those reads are?

I tried using strace for this, but it doesn't seem to show that information.

Edit: There's a nice utility for this: `apt install progress`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to tap into `/proc/$PID/fdinfo` for this purpose. Check out the "The phantom progress bar" section in [Solving problems with proc](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/post/solving-problems-with-proc).

`fdinfo` tracks a process's current position within an open file.

Comment: The "phantom progress bar" worked perfectly and was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: The link is no longer available :(

Comment: There is some useful (and probably related) info in https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17061174

Comment: @Qrilka, thanks for the nostalgic memories from my early days at SO! IIRC this was my first answer to garner more than 5 upvotes. Lamentably I am no longer as active here as I used to be